# llvm pass to detect implicit constructor invocations in a C++ program?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, clang, llvm, clang++

I wanted to know how to write a llvm pass to detect implicit constructor invocations in a C++ file. Like for example say an object is created this way

```cpp
ClassNameTest obj1;
```

It should detect a `ClassNameTest`'s implicit constructor call has been made.

I was not getting to know the appropriate libraries and functions to use for this.

Comment: That's formally neither implict nor explicit.  Default constructor and any value initialization is called same way regardless of how you invoke it or regardless of presence of `explicit` keyword. So it probably would require some deep digging in parser for current context.

Comment: If you consider initialization of a variable an implicit constructor call, then what do you consider an explicit constructor call? (Note that it is impossible to call constructors directly like normal functions in C++.)

Comment: I guess you would have to write an extension to the clang frontend instead of llvm. llvm has no notion of constructors or 'implicit' or 'explicit' calls.